# Using bitwise operator to divide by 0 (Simulation of division by 0)

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

We know that we can use bitwise operators to divide any two numbers. For example:

```
int result = 10 >> 1; //reult would be 5 as it's like dividing 10 by 2^1
```

Is there any chance we can divide a number by 0 using bits manipulation?

**Edit 1:** If I rephrase my question, I want to actually divide a number by zero and break my machine. How do I do that?

**Edit 2:** Let's forget about Java for a moment. Is it feasible for a machine to divide a number by 0 regardless of the programming language used?

**Edit 3:** As it's practically impossible to do this, is there a way we can simulate this using a really small number that approaches 0?

**Another edit:** Some people mentioned that CPU hardware prevents division by 0. I agree, there won't be a direct way to do it. Let's see this code for example:

```
i = 1;
while(0 * i != 10){
    i++;
}
```

Let's assume that there is no cap on the maximum value of `i`. In this case there would be no compiler error nor the CPU would resist this. Now, I want my machine to find the number that's when multiplied with 0 gives me a result (which is obviously never going to happen) or die trying.

So, as there is a way to do this. How can I achieve this by directly manipulating bits?

**Final Edit:** How to perform binary division in Java without using bitwise operators? (I'm sorry, it purely contradicts the title).

**Note:** I've tried simulating divison by 0 and posted my answer. However, I'm looking for a faster way of doing it.

Comment: What result are you expecting from dividing an integer by 0?

Comment: Well, I know it will be not defined. I might cause any overflow and shut down the machine.

Comment: So you want to break your machine, but you don't want to use `/`?

Comment: Usage of `/` will throw an `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: So, I ask again: what result are you expecting from dividing an integer by 0 without `/`?

Comment: (un?)fortunately you can't create black holes this way.

Comment: Does that mean we can never make a machine divide a number by 0?

Comment: @Mr.Singh Yes that what it means. Not only a machine, but anything as the concept just don't exist.

Comment: _"Is it feasible for a machine to divide a number by 0 regardless of the programming language used?"_ the very closest you can get seems to be trying to execute the x86 assembly instruction `DIV`, which triggers the 0x00 [exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table). This may or may not crash your OS.

Comment: @Mr.Singh Ok! Forgetting about Java for a moment, take a look here to see a good answer on why division by 0 isn't conceptually defined: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept. However, what about a really small number that limits/approaches to 0?

Comment: @Mr.Singh Then this is the mathematical limits concept, not a division by 0 as I explained in my answer. You won't have any problem dividing by 0.1, but not using bitwise operator.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Just one last thing, what I'm trying to find out is we know that something divided by 0 is undefined. However, the machine doesn't know that. Whenever we try to perform this operation, all we get is an exception.....a **user-defined exception**. Is there a way a machine can find out on it's own and crash?

Comment: @Mr.Singh Java is too high level to allow a so-known exception like division by 0 to crash the computer. I believe any language that we can write on a computer will be enought validated to not crash the OS.

Comment: @Mr.Singh I've edited my answer to give more details to your comments.

Comment: @Mr.Singh The machine *does* know that divsion by zero is undefined. The engineers making the CPU explicitly wired it to *catch* that case.

Comment: Please see my last edit.

Comment: On your latest edit: If there's no maximum value for `i`, the CPU will repeat the loop infinitely. Anything multiplied by 0 gives 0. Always. Even infinity. Feel free to go ahead and die trying.

Comment: @Mr.Singh The machine is protected at multiple place. You won't crash it with too strong process abuse. Don't you think the JVM would crash before the OS ?

Comment: @Zenith Yes, my friend. I think someone did tell me that when I learned multiplication in primary school. I think you missed the point here. That was just an example of what I was trying to achieve. Jean - well yes, that's a good point. I should try this directly on shell.

Comment: @Mr.Singh Your final edit is strange, what do you mean by *binary division* ? Are you talking about the real math concept ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Yes. However, I'm just trying to find a way to divide two numbers irrespective of the value of divisor(or in other words simulation of division by 0). I was just wondering how is it handled at bit level? Anyways, I think I should do some research by myself and then post the answer. I don't think it is really impossible to divide a number by 0. It would result into an infinite loop and generate a really big number. However, it's not going to break anything. The reason it's not supported by hardware and compilers it because it would be absurd to do so.

Comment: @Mr.Singh division as bit level won't allow you to divide by 0. Basically, convert both number to binary for example `6=110` and `3=11` then simply divide `110/11` which will give you `10` which is the binary representation of `2`, `6/3=2`. This is how binary division is done. You can try all you want, but you will never be able to do or simulate a division by 0 as the concept just don't exist.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Simply divide? I think all we do is addition and subtraction in binary, isn't it? I think I got what I'm looking for. Thanks for discussing this.

Comment: If you run the [restoring division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Restoring_division) algorithm without checking for div-by-zero, you get the highest representable integer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Mr.Singh Mathematical division exists in octal/binary/hexadecimal/decimal or any other decimal. The concept of division is just to separate a number in equals part.

Comment: @harold he is trying to crash a computer simulating a division by 0.

Comment: @harold Thanks for the algorithm. Yes, I was looking for something similar. Jean - Brother, the computer won't crash. We do know that these devices are too powerful.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I just posted an answer. However, I'm looking for something that I could directly implement on binary. Restoring division looks promising though. I should probably try to implement that too. Do you have anything else in mind?

Comment: @harold I just tried restoring division algorithm. This thing is way faster to compute results and it doesn't take long to generate really big numbers. Thanks for sharing man. I've just edited my answer. You might want to look at it.

Comment: @Mr.Singh I see you've added a bounty, what are you precisely expecting as an answer ? There is a lot of edit/comments over this so it's hard to know.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Fastest way to simulate division by 0.

Comment: @Mr.Singh So you want to know what is the fastest possible way to re-writer the algorithm you posted ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard No Sir. I just want to know if there is a better algorithm.

Comment: @Mr.Singh See my edited answer, I think this is what you want, no need to re-write the algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want is a division method faster than **[division by repeated subtraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Division_by_repeated_subtraction)** (which you posted), and that will run indefinitely when you try to divide by zero, you can implement your own version of the **[Goldschmidt division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Goldschmidt_division)**, and not throw an error when the divisor is zero.

The algorithm works like this:

```
1. Create an estimate for the factor f
2. Multiply both the dividend and the divisor by f
3. If the divisor is close enough to 1
    Return the dividend
4. Else
    Go back to step 1
```

Normally, we would need to scale down the dividend and the divisor before starting, so that `0 < divisor < 1` is satisfied. In this case, since we are going to divide by zero, there's no need for this step. We also need to choose an arbitrary precision beyond which we consider the result good enough.

The code, with no check for `divisor == 0`, would be like this:

```
static double goldschmidt(double dividend, double divisor) {
    double epsilon = 0.0000001;
    while (Math.abs(1.0 - divisor) > epsilon) {
        double f = 2.0 - divisor;
        dividend *= f;
        divisor *= f;
    }
    return dividend;
}
```

This is much faster than the division by repeated subtraction method, since it converges to the result quadratically instead of linearly. When dividing by zero, it would not really matter, since both methods won't converge. But if you try to divide by a small number, such as `10^(-9)`, you can clearly see the difference.

**If you don't want the code to run indefinitely**, but to return `Infinity` when dividing by zero, you can modify it to stop when `dividend` reaches `Infinity`:

```
static double goldschmidt(double dividend, double divisor) {
    double epsilon = 0.0000001;
    while (Math.abs(1.0 - divisor) > 0.0000001 && !Double.isInfinite(dividend)) {
        double f = 2.0 - divisor;
        dividend *= f;
        divisor *= f;
    }
    return dividend;
}
```

If the starting values for `dividend` and `divisor` are such that `dividend >= 1.0`  and `divisor == 0.0`, you will get `Infinity` as a result after, at most, `2^10` iterations. That's because the worst case is when `dividend == 1` and you need to multiply it by two (`f = 2.0 - 0.0`) 1024 times to get to `2^1024`, which is greater than [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE).

The Goldschmidt division was implemented in AMD Athlon CPUs. If you want to read about some lower level details, you can check this article:
[Floating Point Division and Square Root Algorithms and Implementation
in the AMD-K7
TM
Microprocessor](http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith14/papers/ARITH14_Oberman.pdf).

**Edit:**

Addressing your comments:

Note that the code for the Restoring Division method you posted iterates 2048 (`2^11`) times. I lowered the value of `n` in your code to 1024, so we could compare both methods doing the same number of iterations.

I ran both implementations 100000 times with `dividend == 1`, which is the worst case for Goldschmidt, and measured the running time like this:

```
long begin = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    goldschmidt(1.0, 0.0); // changed this for restoringDivision(1) to test your code
}
long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - begin) + "ms");
```

The running time was ~290ms for Goldschmidt division and ~23000ms (23 seconds) for your code. So this implementation was about **80x faster** in this test. This is expected, since in one case we are doing `double` multiplications and in the other we are working with `BigInteger`.

The advantage of your implementation is that, since you are using `BigInteger`, you can make your result as large as `BigInteger` supports, while the result here is limited by `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

In practice, when dividing by zero, the Goldschmidt division is doubling the dividend, which is equivalent to a shift left, at each iteration, until it reaches the maximum possible value. So the equivalent using `BigInteger` would be:

```
static BigInteger divideByZero(int dividend) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(dividend)
                     .shiftLeft(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 - ceilLog2(dividend));
}

static int ceilLog2(int n) {
    return (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));
}
```

The function `ceilLog2()` is necessary, so that the `shiftLeft()` will not cause an overflow. Depending on how much memory you have allocated, this will probably result in a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception. So there is a compromise to be made here:

- You can get the division simulation to run really fast, but with a result upper bound of `Double.MAX_VALUE`,

or

- You can get the result to be as big as `2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)`, but it would probably take too much memory and time to get to that limit.

**Edit 2:**

Addressing your new comments:

> Please note that no division is happening in your updated code. It's just trying to find the biggest possible BigInteger

First, let us show that the Goldschmidt division degenerates into a shift left when `divisor == 0`:

```
static double goldschmidt(double dividend, double divisor) {
    double epsilon = 0.0000001;
    while (Math.abs(1.0 - 0.0) > 0.0000001 && !Double.isInfinite(dividend)) {
        double f = 2.0 - 0.0;
        dividend *= f;
        divisor = 0.0 * f;
    }
    return dividend;
}
```

The factor `f` will always be equal to `2.0` and the first `while` condition will always be true. So if we eliminate the redundancies:

```
static double goldschmidt(double dividend, 0) {
    while (!Double.isInfinite(dividend)) {
        dividend *= 2.0;
    }
    return dividend;
}
```

Assuming `dividend` is an `Integer`, we can do the same multiplication using a shift left:

```
static int goldschmidt(int dividend) {
    while (...) {
        dividend = dividend << 1;
    }
    return dividend;
}
```

If the maximum value we can reach is `2^n`, we need to loop `n` times. When `dividend == 1`, this is equivalent to:

```
static int goldschmidt(int dividend) {
    return 1 << n;
}
```

When the `dividend > 1`, we need to subtract `ceil(log2(dividend))` to prevent an overflow:

```
static int goldschmidt(int dividend) {
    return dividend << (n - ceil(log2(dividend));
}
```

Thus showing that the Goldschmidt division is equivalent to a shift left if `divisor == 0`.

> However, shifting the bits to the left would pad bits on the right with 0. Try running this with a small dividend and left shift it (once or twice to check the results). This thing will never get to `2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)`.

Now that we've seen that a shift left by `n` is equivalent to a multiplication by `2^n`, let's see how the `BigInteger` version works. Consider the following examples that show we will get to `2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)` if there is enough memory available and the dividend is a power of 2:

For `dividend = 1`

```
BigInteger.valueOf(dividend).shiftLeft(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 - ceilLog2(dividend))
= BigInteger.valueOf(1).shiftLeft(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 - 0)
= 1 * 2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
= 2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
```

For `dividend = 1024`

```
BigInteger.valueOf(dividend).shiftLeft(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 - ceilLog2(dividend))
= BigInteger.valueOf(1024).shiftLeft(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 - 10)
= 1024 * 2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
= 2^10 * 2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1 - 10)
= 2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
```

If `dividend` is not a power of 2, we will get as close as we can to `2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)` by repeatedly doubling the `dividend`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However `2^10` iterations? It's way too slow. I've just edited my answer. Please try running that and tell me what you think.

Comment: Actually, it's quite fast. I edited my answer with the result of a quick comparison between the two implementations.

Comment: My bad. My apologies. I've misinterpreted that. However, I've just tried running my code again. It hardly took 190ms. Would you mind running it again?

Comment: I've tried this in C# too. Here, check the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MPKzPL). Try running it a couple times and see. Plus, I'm sorry. I don't want to stop at the maximum value of `Double`.

Comment: No problem. Note that I measured the running time for 100000 runs of each method.

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed that. It might be cause of over initialization of `BigInteger` objects. In my loop 3 new objects are created with each iteration. Thanks for poiniting that out.

Comment: @Mr.Singh .... So you want to know the fastest way to loop until BigInteger's max value by step of one ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Not by step of one. Biggest possible number by any means? Should simulate division too.

Comment: @Mr.Singh You need to tell what is your definition of number then. I can easily write a program that will loop forever and increment number by 1.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I did try that brother. If you look at goldschmidt and restoring algorithms. What do we see? Fast way to divide two numbers. I'm only looking for a faster way to do that, where there is no cap on how big a number can get.

Comment: Hey Anderson! When I try to run your code using `goldschmidt(6.0, 3.0)`, the result is `-Infinity`. It's not even dividing properly.

Comment: Yes. As I explained in the answer, the initial values must be scaled down so that 0 < divisor < 1 is satisfied. So you'd need to do goldschmidt(1.0, 0.5) to get the correct result.

Comment: Oh I missed that...my fault.

Comment: @Mr. Singh Updated the answer with the divideByZero() method. I believe that is as far as you can get with BigInteger.

Comment: @AndersonVieira I see what you've done there. That was really clever. However, shifting the bits to the left would pad bits on the right with 0. Try running this with a small dividend and left shift it (once or twice to check the results). This thing will never get to `2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)`. Please do correct me if I'm wrong. +1 for a different approach though.

Comment: @AndersonVieira Please note that no division is happening in your updated code. It's just trying to find the biggest possible BigInteger which can be achieved by using `BigInteger.pow` too.

Comment: @Mr. Singh Updated the answer to address your comments.

Comment: @AndersonVieira Bravo! Everything makes sense. Thank you so much for the explanation. One last thing I'd like to add is the maximum value should actually be `(2 ^ Integer.MAX_VALUE) - 1` instead of `2 ^ (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)` just like the maximum number that can be represented by 3 bits is `(2^3) -1` instead of `2 ^ (3 - 1)`. My mistake. I can't edit my comment. However, please do edit your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is impossible.

The division by 0 is mathematically impossible. The concept just don't exist, so there is no way to simulate it.

If you were actually trying to do limits operation (divide by `0+` or `0-`) then there is still no way to do it using bitwise as it will only allow you to divide by power of two.

Here an exemple using bitwise operation only to divide by power of 2

```
10 >> 1 = 5
```

Looking at the comments you posted, if what you want is simply to exit your program when an user try to divide by 0 you can simply validate it :

```
if(dividant == 0)
    System.exit(/*Enter here the exit code*/);
```

That way you will avoid the ArithmeticException.

---

After exchanging a couple of comments with you, it seems like what you are trying to do is crash the operating system dividing by 0.

Unfortunately for you, as far as I know, any language that can be written on a computer are validated enought to handle the division by 0.

Just think to a simple calculator that you pay 1$, try to divide by 0 and it won't even crash, it will simply throw an error msg. This is probably validated at the processor level anyway.

---

**Edit**

After multiple edits/comments to your question, it seems like you are trying to retrieve the *Infinity* dividing by a `0+` or `0-` that is very clause to 0.

You can achieve this with double/float division.

```
System.out.println(1.0f / 0.0f);//prints infinity
System.out.println(1.0f / -0.0f);//prints -Infinity
System.out.println(1.0d / 0.0d);//prints infinity
System.out.println(1.0d / -0.0d);//prints -Infinity
```

Note that even if you write 0.0, the value is not really equals to 0, it is simply really close to it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, I'm looking for a solution where there is no limit on how big a number can get. `System.out.println(1.0f / 0.0f);` is (almost) same as manually printing `infinity` on the console when the dividend is `0`.

Comment: @Mr.Singh You mean you want to reach `Long.MAX_VALUE` ?

Comment: Most probably max value of `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, since you can only divide by a power of 2 using right shift.

Comment: Yes Sir, I do know that. Is there any other way we could do this?

Comment: There is no exponent `x` where `2^x = 0`

Comment: @Clashsoft That's correct. It's undefined.

Answer (score 1):

One way to simulate division of unsigned integers (irrespective of divisor used) is by division by repeated subtraction:

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger("0");
int divisor = 0;
int dividend = 2;

while(dividend >=  divisor){

    dividend = dividend - divisor;              
    result = result.add(BigInteger.ONE);            

}
```

Second way to do this is by using [Restoring Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Restoring_division) algorithm (Thanks @harold) which is way faster than the first one:

```
int num = 10;
BigInteger den = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger p = new BigInteger(new Integer(num).toString());
int n = 2048; //Can be changed to find the biggest possible number (i.e. upto 2^2147483647 - 1). Currently it shows 2^2048 - 1 as output 
den = den.shiftLeft(n);

BigInteger q = new BigInteger("0");

for(int i = n; i > 0; i -= 1){
    q = q.shiftLeft(1);
    p = p.multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
    p = p.subtract(den);

    if(p.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) == 1 
        || p.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) == 0){
        q = q.add(new BigInteger("1"));
    } else {
        p = p.add(den);
    }
}

System.out.println(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have indicated, you cannot mathematically divide by 0.

However if you want methods to divide by 0, there are some constants in Double you could use. For example you could have a method

```
public static double divide(double a, double b){
    return b == 0 ? Double.NaN : a/b;
}
```

or

```
public static double posLimitDivide(double a, double b){
    if(a == 0 && b == 0)
        return Double.NaN;
    return b == 0 ? (a > 0 ? Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY : Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) : a/b;
```

Which would return the limit of a/x where x approaches +b.

These should be ok, as long as you account for it in whatever methods use them. And by OK I mean bad, and could cause indeterminate behavior later if you're not careful. But it is a clear way to indicate the result with an actual value rather than an exception.